# Are questions about setting up a business/writing a business plan on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

That question came up when I was reading [this user question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/27527/what-is-the-target-market-of-a-commercial-photography-business-partnership). Reading the [help](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) did not help me.

On the one hand, I tend to consider a business (location) as a workplace, even for a one-person company, but on the other hand the user does not have a business yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Questions about the business domain itself are off-topic, same as questions about what job to take or what degrees/certifications to pursue.

However, questions about setting up the workplace itself, like a question we had not long ago about finding office space for a one-person business, are about the workplace and are on-topic.  (The question you linked to isn't that, but the wording of this meta question could be interpreted as asking about this too, hence this paragraph.)

Answer (score 1):

No.

[A business plan is inherently subjective and predicated on many localized factors.](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/27527/what-is-the-target-market-of-a-commercial-photography-business-partnership#comment68425_27527)

Comment: The question was too localized but just a business plan is pretty straightforward.  That question was a homework question, but in general the answer would not be too subjective to answer, though it is off topic.